# PHP, MYSQL, Echo looped rows in single column

Tags: php, mysql, loops, rows

Good afternoon everyone,

I have some php code that is in a while loop that shows mysql data which is a list of scheduled jobs. I have altered the code to now schedule multiple techs instead of just single techs. However, I am trying to get the list of tech names to show in the tech field but as you can see from the screen shot it is writing the second tech name in the Work Order Column instead of in the tech field and pushing everything over. The screenshot shows the first 2 jobs functioning correctly as each of those jobs only have 1 tech scheduled however the 3rd and 4th jobs have multiple techs. Any input on what I am doing wrong would be great.

```
    while ($b_row =mysql_fetch_array ($jobresult) ) {
$job_id = stripslashes($b_row[job_id]);
$status = stripslashes($b_row[status]);
$order_no = stripslashes($b_row[order_no]);
$cust = stripslashes($b_row[cust]);
$region = stripslashes($b_row[region]);
$type = stripslashes($b_row[type]);
$qty = stripslashes($b_row[qty]);
$job_name = stripslashes($b_row[job_name]);
$job_add = stripslashes($b_row[job_add]);
$job_add2 = stripslashes($b_row[job_add2]);
$job_city = stripslashes($b_row[job_city]);
$job_state = stripslashes($b_row[job_state]);
$job_zip = stripslashes($b_row[job_zip]);
$job_contact = stripslashes($b_row[job_contact]);
$job_phone1 = stripslashes($b_row[job_phone1]);
$job_phone2 = stripslashes($b_row[job_phone2]);
$sch_dte = $b_row[sch_dte];
$cust_no = $b_row[cust_no];
$tech_id = $b_row[tech_id];
    $tech_id2 = $b_row[tech_id2];

$sch_time = strftime("%I:%M %p",$sch_dte);
$sch_dte = strftime("%m/%d/%y",$sch_dte);

if ($order_no == "") { $order_no = "&nbsp;"; }
if ($cust_no == "") { $cust_no = "&nbsp;"; }
if ($qty == "") { $qty = "&nbsp;"; }
if ($job_name == "") { $job_name = "&nbsp;"; }
if ($job_contact == "") { $job_contact = "&nbsp;"; }

$gettype = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM service_types WHERE ((type_id ='$type'));",$link);
while ($d_row =mysql_fetch_array ($gettype) ) {
$service_type = stripslashes($d_row[service_type]);
}

$getstatus = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status WHERE ((status_id ='$status'));",$link);
while ($e_row =mysql_fetch_array ($getstatus) ) {
$stat_rep = stripslashes($e_row[short_status]);
}

/*$gettech = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tech WHERE ((tech_id ='$tech_id'));",$link);
while ($e_row =mysql_fetch_array ($gettech) ) {
$tech_fname = stripslashes($e_row[tech_fname]);
$tech_lname = stripslashes($e_row[tech_lname]);
$tech_name = "$tech_fname $tech_lname";
}*/


$comresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs_comments WHERE ((job_id ='$job_id'));",$link);
$chk_com = mysql_num_rows($comresult);

if ($chk_com != "0") { $com_yes = "Y"; } else { $com_yes = "N"; }

echo "<tr align=\"center\" ";
if ($bgchk == "1") {
echo "bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\"> ";
$bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";
$bgchk = "0"; }
else {
echo "bgcolor=\"#E8E8E8\"> ";
$bgcolor = "#E8E8E8";
$bgchk = "1"; }


if ($chk_job == "") {  echo "<td colspan=\"$pdf_colums\">No Jobs currently listed</td>"; }

else {

if ($grp_edit == "1" AND $action != "pdf") {
echo "<td><input name=\"mu[$rw_count]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"mu[$rw_count]\" value=\"$job_id\" /></td>"; }
echo "<td>$sch_dte <br>$sch_time</td>";
//echo "<td>$tech_name $tech_name2</td>";
```

//***CODE IN QUESTION LIES HERE

```
    $techteam = array($tech_id2);
    $sql = 'SELECT tech_fname, tech_lname FROM tech WHERE tech_id IN (' . implode(',', $techteam) . ')';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tech_fname = stripslashes($row[tech_fname]);
$tech_lname = stripslashes($row[tech_lname]);
    echo "<td>$row[tech_fname] $row[tech_lname],<br></td>";
    }

echo "<td>$order_no</td>";
echo "<td>$cust</td>";
echo "<td>$region</td>";
echo "<td>$service_type</td>";
echo "<td>$qty</td>";
echo "<td>$cust_no</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "$job_name<br>$job_add ";
if ($job_add2 != "") { echo "<br>$job_add2 "; }
echo "<br>$job_city $job_state $job_zip";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "$job_contact<br>$job_phone1";
if ($job_phone2 != "") { echo "<br />$job_phone2"; }
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a href=\"admin.php?viewjob=$job_id\"><img src=\"images/edit_all.gif\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\" border=\"0\"></a>";
echo "</td>";
}
```

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcISx.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing a new table cell for each tech.

`<td>$row[tech_fname] $row[tech_lname],<br></td>` should instead be `$row[tech_fname] $row[tech_lname],<br/>` and your while loop should be encasing (placed between) the `<td>`, `</td>` tags.

Also, you're stripping the slashes from `$row[tech_fname]` and `$row[tech_lname]` but you're never using those variables. I assume you want to use those variables in the echo statement as I've edited my answer to include?

Your code should resemble the following:

```
echo '<td>';
$counter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tech_fname = stripslashes($row[tech_fname]);
    $tech_lname = stripslashes($row[tech_lname]);
    echo "$tech_fname $tech_lname";
    if($counter != 0) echo ",<br>";
    $counter++;
}
echo '</td>';
```

As a side note, you should really consider moving away from `mysql` and onto `mysqli` or `PDO` (or other methods that use prepared statements) so that you can help prevent SQL injection and other attacks